# How do I edit a message inside of another channel by message ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to edit a message that's in another channel that the bot can see, when you use the command from another channel.

I tried using this method but it didn't work. What's the new method since this one is probably outdated?

```js
client.channels.cache.get('Channel ID').fetchMessage('Message ID').edit(embed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetchMessages()` is now `.messages.fetch()` and it returns a promise:

```js
  client.channels.cache
    .get('Channel ID')
    .messages.fetch('Message ID')
    .then((msg) => msg.edit(embed));
```